# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found only on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, xcode

I try to debug my app with XCode on my device, it works with every Phone except iPhone 5 then I get the message:

> "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"

When I try to renew the certificate with the organizer, Xcode crashes.

Comment: Are you using the newest Xcode (4.6)?

Comment: Yes I've got all available updates from the AppStore

Comment: And you're on a 'legal' mac?

Comment: Also, have you tried downloading your provisioning profile from the developer portal?

Comment: Its a completely legal MacBook Pro, I don't try to get it manually because I don't know if it interferes with the profile managed by Xcode

Comment: I found this answer worked for me in Xcode 5.0 (for anyone looking): http://stackoverflow.com/a/18942735/405244

Answer (score 19):

I had the same exact problem and solved it following the guidelines from... Apple :)

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933

To ensure the Xcode project Bundle Identifier is compatible with the App ID associated with your Provisioning Profiles, perform the following steps.

- Choose the Xcode "View" menu > Navigators > Project.
- Select your root project folder in the upper left corner.

  - (The Project Editor will appear in the center pane.)
- Click on your target in the "TARGETS" section
- Click the "Build Settings" tab.
- Scroll down to the "Code Signing Identity" section.
- If you are building to your development device, click the Value column under "Debug" that is to the right of "Any iOS SDK".
- In the provisioning profile selection pop-up, check that the current selection reads "For Application Identifiers: " with the intended App ID.
- If you are building a distribution binary, click the value column under "Release" that is to the right of "Any iOS SDK".
- In the provisioning profile selection pop-up, check that the current selection reads "For Application Identifiers: " with the intended App ID.

Comment: Thanks for putting the answer inline. I had a similar problem -- I'm on more than one development team and xcode chose the wrong one for my development phone. Make sure you choose the right identity if you have more than one.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada, I too chose the wrong team and now can't get the option again. How did you change teams in Xcode?

Comment: @RichardBronosky Click on the project in Proj Nav -> Project -> All -> Search : "Code Signing" -> Code Signing Identity -> Make sure "Debug" is not just "iPhone Developer", it should be "iPhone Developer: Your Name (THE_ID_YOU_WANT)"

Answer (score 9):

I have same issue because my device UDID start with "FFFFFFFF". This UDID is wrong.

Now i taken UDID from Xcode.

1. Connect your device to mac
2. Xcode --> Window --> Devices --> Click on your device --> Identifier(UDID)

[image]

Added this UDID in my apple developer account and re-generated the provisioning profiles.

Now it is working fine

Comment: I solved it this way as well. I changed my phone because the power button broke and I forgot completely about it being a new phone.

Comment: Old, but thanks it solved it for me, forgot too. I also had to regenerate the provisioning profile with all devices selected as it was invalid in the member centre.

Answer (score 4):

Following worked for me:

- Click on project name from the project navigator window.
- From the Target section, select the project's target name.
- Click on "Build Settings".
- Go to "Code Signing" section and for the "Provisioning Profile" setting choose "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: Wildcard AppID" or you can select app specific provisioning profile name.

Note: I had changed this to distribution provisioning profile for the app when building for distribution but did not change it back when resuming work on the project.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem, and discovered that my solution was to check the date on the device.  If the date on the device was in the future, and AFTER the date when your provisioning profile expires, then this error message would appear.  After changing the date back to the current date, or a date that is before your provisioning profile expires, then your app should successfully load on your device.

Definitely consider the other solutions first before this one.  This was a unique situation for me, as I was testing an app that required changing the device date, and couldn't understand why one moment the app was loading, and why the other moment it wasn't.

All the best.

Comment: one upvote for mentioning the date on device is greater than the expiry date of provisioning profile

Comment: Wow, this was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all these great answers, also make sure that you build scheme's Run section is set to "Debug" and NOT to "Release".

Answer (score 0):

for me it was because my provisioning file capabilities did not match xcodes.  There was a warning on the general tab of your target under the identity section right under the team designation. It has an option to fix the issue which issued a new provisoning profile.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was simply that it was a new year and Apple required me to re-register my iPhone. This whole code signing business with iOS development is whole lot harder than it needs to be. Android's approach is so much easier.