# Can't submit Xcode 5 App to to iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, xcode5, app-store-connect

I've archived my project but when I send it to iTunes Connect Xcode is crashing... My steps:
Archive -> Go to organizer -> distribute -> app store -> log in -> download identities -> choose my account -> crash. I can't submit my app...
Any ideas?

Comment: This one helped me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913964/xcode-5-crashes-on-appstore-validation

Answer (score -1):

1.Restart the computer
2.Close xcode, let it run for a little, then quit. 
3.repeat these steps until it works.