# No Identities are available for signing in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, ad-hoc-distribution

I have followed every direction given here but in-vain.

Created/Added distribution provisioning profile (1000 times)
Deleted and created certificates. Added them to keychain. Create distribution profile using new certificate.

I get no warning or error when i build the app. It is only when i am trying to archive the app to create ad-hoc distribution i get No Identities are available for signing warning. If I try use download Identities, Xcode crashes.

**This started to happen ever since I upgraded to Xcode 5.**

Certificate as well as profile have Valid status. Also I made sure to pick correct distribution provisioning profile under code signing identity for both target and project.

Here is one of the links i followed.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592074/no-identities-are-available-for-signing

Comment: I found this answer worked for me (Xcode 5.0) http://stackoverflow.com/a/18942735/405244

Comment: it is duplicated please avoid redundancy questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746703/no-identities-are-available-for-signing-xcode-5

Answer (score 11):

Xcode 5

1) Recreate the distribution profile in developer.apple.com with a different name.

download / open

> cmd + , - > preferences > accounts > view details  > sync /refresh

3) under the Build Settings

> Provisioning profile > Release >  Select the new Provisioning profile.

Above - in code signing identity and it should magically appear.

Comment: It's important that the profile is a different name.  It doesn't seem to work otherwise.

Comment: To select Preferences/Accounts/View Details/Click-refresh-icon worked fine for me. I could create and Validate/Distribute an archive after that. I didn't have to modify build settings, just used defaults.

Comment: Working like a charm, why this bug happens? (I change nothing, just start my computer, make the archive/distribute and boom ;-(

Answer (score 4):

Ran into this issue today also when trying to create Ad Hoc builds for upload to TestFlightApp. Fixed it by updating the Target - Code Signing Provisioning Profile section. Set the Release Provisioning Profile to point to your Ad Hoc profile. Then when you create a package from the Archive menu item it will use the correct profile for Ad Hoc distribution. This looks to be new in XCode 5.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly how i have it but still no luck.

Comment: @KurtWatts - Have you ensured that you do not have duplicate development/distribution certificates installed in keychain? I've run into issues with that in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. I spent about 3 weeks on it. I remade my app from scratch. I must have remade certificates and provisioning profiles dozens of times. Everything was case sensitive and matched perfectly. Everything was set in both the project and target sections.

In the end, I decided to skip ad hoc validation and chose a regular distribution profile validation. Then the app finally validated perfectly, no issues.

And when I clicked distribute instead of validate, XCode let me choose the ad hoc profile, and thus far I've been able to beta test smoothly.

In short, I haven't been able to validate with an ad hoc profile, but I've found the way around it. Haven't submitted to the App Store yet, but the fact that I was able to validate with a regular distribution profile gives me hope.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Trying the "skip validation for ad hoc build" approach now. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I think the solution is to set the provisioning profile and identity in both the project and target sections of the project navigator. After I did the on in the project, the identities were found. 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Xcode to submit the app I have used the Application Loader app based on [this tutorial](http://appdevelopermagazine.com/825/2013/10/25/Guide%3a-How-to-Publish-from-Xcode-5-To-The-Apple-App-Store/).

I ran into validation issues though - oh joy :-P

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Xcode` >> `Preferences` and associate with an apple developer program with the appleID linked with your current provisioning profile.
[image]

Comment: That is already there. I still deleted and re-added but no luck. This sucks big time.

Comment: Does anyone know how to contact apple with this Xcode issue? I already have Technical Support Incident registered but haven't heard anything

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth I had a very similar issue.  It didn't start happening to me after Xcode 5 but after I accidentally reset my keychain.  (I was trying to reset the keychain of a remote machine, and accidentally did it to my own.  Doh!)

Once you get to that screen in Xcode you are done.  Any option you select from there results in an Xcode crash.  100% repeatable.   I reported that and hopefully it will get fixed in a future update.

The solution that I stumbled into was that I didn't have to correct provisioning profile on my machine.  I had to download it double click and get it into the keychain.  I don't actually see it in the keychain but it shows up in Xcode where I suddenly get a new option in code signing identities that didn't exist before.  I set this to Automatic.

If you had told me that this was the solution to this problem I would have laughed at you because I would have said I ALREADY DID THAT 5 TIMES!  Maybe in the process of resetting, revoking, and reinstalling I forgot it?  Although I can see all of the certificates in keychain, I don't actually know how to see the provisioning profiles.  For me, when I put in the new provisioning profile it shows up in Xcode as code signing identity option that wasn't there before.