# Signing identity problems in XCode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing

So I'm trying to validate an app for the purpose of beta testing, but when I try to validate an archive, it tells me:

"No identities are available for signing"

And when I hit the "Download Identities" button and choose from my development team, it says:

"No identities were available/ An administrator must request identities before they can be downloaded."

I've revoked my certificates and made them again, and I've deleted the provisioning profiles and made them all again for ad hoc distribution and development (I also deleted all the provisioning profiles from my keychain).

I made sure that my bundle identifier matches the app record in iTunes Connect and the distribution provisioning profiles I've created from the iOS Dev Center. The bundle identifiers match.

All of the certificates and distribution profiles show up under my "Accounts" under "Preferences" in XCode. The accounts shows that I have valid certificates and provisioning profiles.

I also made sure that the correct distribution provisioning profile was selected under "Code Signing" in the Build Settings.

Any other ideas about what I could do, or what the problem might be?

I've been scouring every stackflow post I could find. Tried the checked answer on this one most recently and it didn't work:

[XCode 5 Crashes on AppStore Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913964/xcode-5-crashes-on-appstore-validation/18942735#18942735)

Any other ideas?

Comment: your problem is fixed?

Comment: @MirkoCatalano I clicked the "Download" option under the certificates, and then I clicked on the file in the download bar at the bottom of the browser. I also exported the developer and distribution certificates from XCode. I still got the same result. Doesn't seem to work yet, unfortunately.

Comment: you made these certificates? if yes you made this certificates from the same machine where you're working now?

Comment: That's right. I made the certificates from the same machine I'm working on now

Comment: this is really strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me I had an Ad Hoc Distribution Profile but needed an App Store Distribution Profile.

Comment: I found this to be true. Now that I have an App Store Distribution Profile, it also recognizes my ad hoc profile, whereas it did not before.

Answer (score 4):

Try following these instructions.  Basically there are multiple places where you have to tell Xcode what your bundle identifier is and what the provisioning profile is.  I can't believe this stuff is totally overlooked in the iOS Developer Distribution Guide by Apple.

http://anthonytietjen.blogspot.com/2012/08/overcoming-trouble-validating-your.html

Also, go into Build Settings for your project and go to Code Signing.  Make sure the Code Signing Identities are all set to the iDevice Distribution App ID you created in iTunes Connect as well as the Provisioning Profile set to the Provisioning Profile you painstakingly created in the iOS Development Center as well (that Ad Hoc provisioning profile file you created and downloaded into Xcode.)

Apple was great at walking you through creating the Distribution Certificate and Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile, but when it comes down to getting things bundled up in Xcode, they left a lot out.

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH1-SW1

Also, I would say that if you still can't get it working with an Ad Hoc provisioning profile, try generating an App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile within the "Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles" portion of the Development center , import it into Xcode (by refreshing the provisioning profile list under Xcode->preferences->accounts->details->refresh button) and go through the validation process of your archive again. I'm not sure if it's because Xcode can't validate an Archive with an Ad Hoc profile or what, but it seems to pick up the Distribution Provisioning Profile just fine and allows you to validate.  Don't worry, even if you don't validate the archive with the Ad Hoc provisioning profile, you can still create the .ipa for your archive by hitting the Distribute button in Organizer->Archives and choosing the Ad Hoc profile so that you can beta test it.

Comment: Though these steps didn't work for me, this is a GREAT post. I'd just like to say that I figured my issue out -- I had an Ad Hoc Distribution Profile but needed an App Store Distribution Profile.

Comment: Your last suggestion: create a store profile worked! You are a prince. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to install in your machine the certificates that you generate in you Apple account for development and distribution your app (these is not the provisioning profile)

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. For me it worked to open Xcode Preferences dialog and select Accounts, click View Details and click the refresh icon. That downloaded the distribution provisioning profile I had created for my app. I could then create an archive and do Validate/Distribute.

Answer (score 2):

Summary of studying responses from all over.  Get three things right.

1 - Your **bundleID** has to match what you have in the **iTunesConnect**, exactly.
    **CHECK**:  Xcode > Project>Info>Custom iOS Target Properties > Bundle Identifier
    **COMPARE IT TO:** http://itunesconnect.apple.com > Manage Your Apps > [Your app name] > BundleID 

2 - If you're building for **AD HOC** distribution, don't try to upload to the iTunes store. You choose this when you pick your provisioning profile.  If you want to upload to the iTunes store, you have to choose provisioning for **APP STORE**.
    **CHECK**:  http://developer.apple.com/membercenter > Certificates, Identifiers, Profiles > Provisioning Profiles> and click the plus sign to create your profile.

3 - Make sure that in your Xcode code signing is set up correctly.  You need to have two things right here.  You need to have one of your distribution identities selected AND you have to have the right provisioning profile selected in this section.
     **CHECK**: Xcode > Project > Build Settings > Code Signing