# Xcode 5 crashing during validation

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have an app developed in Xcode and tested with development devices so that I know that it's working properly.

During validation archive in organizer getting following error of Xcode

> Process:         Xcode [2220] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:         5.0 (3332.25) Build Info:
>   IDEApplication-3332025000000000~2 Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:  launchd [135] User ID:         501
>
> Date/Time:       2013-10-30 14:39:31.055 +0530 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.8.5 (12F37) Report Version:  10
>
> Interval Since Last Report:          4524 sec Crashes Since Last
>   Report:           4 Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  4475 sec
>   Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   4 Anonymous UUID:
>   A5C3ABA8-1834-EF2E-9C44-418AD4CC9A3E
>
> Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   EXC_I386_GPFLT
>
> Application Specific Information: objc_msgSend() selector name:
>   respondsToSelector: ProductBuildVersion: 5A1413
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00007fff8f3db510 objc_msgSend_vtable5
>   + 16 1   com.apple.AppKit                 0x00007fff889913b2 +[NSTextInputContext currentInputContext] + 128 2   com.apple.AppKit                 0x00007fff88990b81 -[NSApplication updateWindows] + 94 3
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff88bdbd9f **38-[NSApplication
>   setWindowsNeedUpdate:]_block_invoke_02349 + 76 4
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8af5f417
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23 5   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8af5f381
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 369 6   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8af3a7b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 728 7   com.apple.CoreFoundation 
>     0x00007fff8af3a0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290 8   com.apple.HIToolbox
>     0x00007fff8ddfceb4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209 9
>   com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fff8ddfcb94
>   ReceiveNextEventCommon + 166 10  com.apple.HIToolbox
>     0x00007fff8ddfcae3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62 11 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff8898f533 _DPSNextEvent + 685
>   12  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff8898edf2 -[NSApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128 13 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff889861a3 -[NSApplication run]
>   + 517 14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8892abd6 NSApplicationMain + 869 15  libdyld.dylib
>     0x00007fff9425d7e1 start + 1
>
> Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff878eed16 kevent + 10 1
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff8aeeedea _dispatch_mgr_invoke
>   + 883 2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8aeee9ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54
>
> Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 
>     0x00007fff878ec686 mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff878ebc42 mach_msg + 70 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8af35233 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195 3
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8af3a916 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1078 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8af3a0e2
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290 5   com.apple.Foundation
>
>     0x00007fff8a7d5546 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] +
>   356 6   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8a833562
>   _*NSThread*_main** + 1345 7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8fa60772 _pthread_start + 327 8   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff878ee322 __select + 10 1   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8af79f46 __CFSocketManager + 1302 2   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa60772 _pthread_start + 327 3   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff878ec686
>   mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff878ebc42 mach_msg + 70 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8af35233 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195 3
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8af3a916 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1078 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8af3a0e2
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290 5   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase
>
>     0x000000010fff075a -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener
>   listenerThreadImplementation] + 164 6   com.apple.Foundation
>
>     0x00007fff8a833562 _*NSThread*_main** + 1345 7   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa60772 _pthread_start + 327 8   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 5:: DYMobileDeviceManager 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff878ec686 mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff878ebc42 mach_msg + 70 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8af35233 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195 3
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8af3a916 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1078 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8af3a0e2
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290 5   com.apple.Foundation
>
>     0x00007fff8a8387ee -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 268
>   6   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8a7d11aa
>   -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74 7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation   0x00000001152189bb
>   -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 132 8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8a833562 _*NSThread*_main** +
>   1345 9   libsystem_c.dylib                0x00007fff8fa60772
>   _pthread_start + 327 10  libsystem_c.dylib                0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 6:: CVDisplayLink 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff878ee0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa64fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869 2   com.apple.CoreVideo
>     0x00007fff916b02a1 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 689 3
>   com.apple.CoreVideo               0x00007fff916affd7 startIOThread(void*)
>   + 148 4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8fa60772 _pthread_start + 327 5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 7:: JavaScriptCore::BlockFree 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff878ee0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa64fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869 2
>   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fff91e96b66
>   WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 118 3
>   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fff920b9bfa
>   JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 90 4
>   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fff920cf25f
>   WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15 5   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa60772 _pthread_start + 327 6   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 8:: JavaScriptCore::Marking 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff878ee0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa64fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869 2
>   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fff9201c9d4
>   JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) +
>   212 3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fff9201c8b6
>   JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 214 4
>   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fff920cf25f
>   WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15 5   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa60772 _pthread_start + 327 6   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 9:: JavaScriptCore::Marking 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff878ee0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa64fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869 2
>   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fff9201c9d4
>   JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) +
>   212 3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fff9201c8b6
>   JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 214 4
>   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fff920cf25f
>   WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15 5   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa60772 _pthread_start + 327 6   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 10:: JavaScriptCore::Marking 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff878ee0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa64fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869 2
>   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fff9201c9d4
>   JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) +
>   212 3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fff9201c8b6
>   JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 214 4
>   com.apple.JavaScriptCore          0x00007fff920cf25f
>   WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15 5   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa60772 _pthread_start + 327 6   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 11: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff878ee0fa
>   **psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                0x00007fff8fa64fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869 2
>
>   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore      0x000000010f394006 -[XCBlockQueue
>   _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 506 3   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fff8a833562 _*NSThread*_main** + 1345 4   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa60772 _pthread_start + 327 5   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 12: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff878ee0fa
>   **psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                0x00007fff8fa64fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869 2
>
>   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore      0x000000010f394006 -[XCBlockQueue
>   _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 506 3   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fff8a833562 _*NSThread*_main** + 1345 4   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa60772 _pthread_start + 327 5   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 13: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff878ee0fa
>   **psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                0x00007fff8fa64fb9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869 2
>
>   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore      0x000000010f394006 -[XCBlockQueue
>   _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 506 3   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fff8a833562 _*NSThread*_main** + 1345 4   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa60772 _pthread_start + 327 5   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 14: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff878ec686
>   mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff878ebc42 mach_msg + 70 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8af35233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195 3
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8af3a916 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1078 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8af3a0e2
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290 5   com.apple.DebugSymbols
>     0x00007fff90cfd590 SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 356 6
>   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa60772 _pthread_start + 327
>   7   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start +
>   13
>
> Thread 15: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff878ee0fa
>   **psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                0x00007fff8fa64ff3 _pthread_cond_wait + 927 2   com.apple.Foundation 
>     0x00007fff8a85e883 -[NSCondition waitUntilDate:] + 357 3
>
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8a85e6d9 -[NSConditionLock
>   lockWhenCondition:beforeDate:] + 235 4   com.apple.CSServiceClient
>
>     0x000000010c8faf79 -[CSLogger loggerThread:] + 257 5
>
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8a833562 _*NSThread*_main** +
>   1345 6   libsystem_c.dylib                0x00007fff8fa60772
>   _pthread_start + 327 7   libsystem_c.dylib                0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 16:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff878ec686 mach_msg_trap + 10 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff878ebc42 mach_msg + 70 2
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8af35233
>   __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8af3a916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8af3a0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290 5   com.apple.CFNetwork
>     0x00007fff8985bd9f CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 463 6
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8a7bb536 +[NSURLConnection
>   sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 281 7
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8a93189d
>   __67+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_0 + 70
>   8   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff8aeeff01
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15 9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8aeec0b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8 10  libdispatch.dylib
>     0x00007fff8aeed1fa _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 304 11 
>   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa62cdb _pthread_wqthread +
>   404 12  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa4d191
>   start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 17:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff878ec686 mach_msg_trap + 10 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff878ebc42 mach_msg + 70 2
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff8af35233
>   __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff8af3a916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff8af3a0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290 5   com.apple.CFNetwork
>     0x00007fff8985bd9f CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 463 6
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8a7bb536 +[NSURLConnection
>   sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 281 7
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8a93189d
>   __67+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_0 + 70
>   8   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff8aeeff01
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15 9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8aeec0b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8 10  libdispatch.dylib
>     0x00007fff8aeed1fa _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 304 11 
>   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa62cdb _pthread_wqthread +
>   404 12  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa4d191
>   start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 18: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff878ee6d6
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa62f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25 2   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa62ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412 3   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d191 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 19: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff878ee6d6
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa62f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25 2   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa62ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412 3   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d191 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 20: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff878ee6d6
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa62f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25 2   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa62ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412 3   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d191 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 21: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff878ee6d6
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa62f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25 2   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa62ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412 3   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d191 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 22:: com.apple.appkit-heartbeat 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff878ee386 **semwait_signal + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib
>
>     0x00007fff8faea7c8 nanosleep + 163 2   libsystem_c.dylib
>
>     0x00007fff8faea6df usleep + 54 3   com.apple.AppKit
>
>     0x00007fff88b74838 -[NSUIHeartBeat _heartBeatThread:] + 543 4
>
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8a833562 _*NSThread*_main** +
>   1345 5   libsystem_c.dylib                0x00007fff8fa60772
>   _pthread_start + 327 6   libsystem_c.dylib                0x00007fff8fa4d1a1 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 23: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff878ee6d6
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa62f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25 2   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa62ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412 3   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d191 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 24: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff878ee6d6
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa62f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25 2   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa62ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412 3   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d191 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 25: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff878ee6d6
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff8fa62f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25 2   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa62ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412 3   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8fa4d191 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
>   0xd00007f9f02bd29f  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x7031b9c2f7283401 
>   rdx: 0x00007fff891f9814   rdi: 0x00007f9f02070b30  rsi:
>   0x00007fff77c10ae0  rbp: 0x00007fff56518540  rsp: 0x00007fff56518518
>   r8: 0x0000000000000007   r9: 0x00000000afd3bb8e  r10:
>   0x000000011352fc40  r11: 0x00007fff77b82b70   r12: 0x00007fff565185b0 
>   r13: 0x00007f9efc84bb88  r14: 0x00007f9f02070b30  r15:
>   0x00007f9f0760cdf0   rip: 0x00007fff8f3db510  rfl: 0x0000000000000246 
>   cr2: 0x000000010c86d2e0 Logical CPU: 0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913964/xcode-5-crashes-on-appstore-validation

Comment: solution give on that link not working in my case

Answer (score 0):

This is an Xcode crash, it has nothing to do with your apps' code. Update to xcode 5.0.1 to see if it fixes your issue. If not, move xcode to the trash and reinstall it from the Mac App Store.